# Undefined local variable or method `‘welcome' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fd561953218>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I follow the ruby on rails tutorial guide but I keep having the error as stated in my title. I have totally no idea why does it appear.

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root ‘application#hello’ 

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
    end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def hello  
    render text: “Hello”
  end
end
```

Please advise me on this because I have been trying around and even reinstalling everything again based on the Ruby on Rails tutorial.

Comment: You are supposed to surround `application#hello` with `'`, and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: What do you mean by it? surround it with ' ?

Comment: the errors i get is as follows


config/routes.rb:6: in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Comment: You are surrounding them with `’`, and I'm saying you to surround them with `'`! Did you get it?

Comment: yes, i have just change it. But it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `root ‘application#hello’`.
It looks like your system uses wrong symbol for single quotation mark (the one you are using is 8216 unicode character and you should be using the 39 one). Also in your controller `render text: “Hello”` would throw an error.

The lines should be `root 'application#hello'` and `render text: "Hello"`

This may be changed in your system keyboard settings. Cannot be more accurate since I don't know what system are you using but the issue is definitely in wrong symbols for single\double quotations.

Comment: Hey thanks alot man. I solved it. Changed the setting on my system. :D

Comment: You may want to mark the answer as correct if it solves your problem.